# Vuex, не понимаю как подключить хранилище к компоненту

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Есть index.js в папке store

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import PassportPart from './PassportPart'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
modules: {
    PassportPart,
  },
});
```

есть модуль PassportPart.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
state: {
    patient_data: {
        last_name: "",
        first_name: "",
        patronymic: "",
        birth_date: null,
        state: "",
        gender: ""
    }
},
getters: {
    PATIENT_DATA(state) {
        return state.patient_data;
    }
},
mutations: {
    SET_PAT_DATA(state, payload) {
        state.patient_data.last_name = payload.data.last_name;
        //все остальное аналогично
    },
},
actions: {
    GET_PAT_DATA ({commit}) {
        axios.get('какая то ссылка', {headers: {}, }).then(res => {
            commit('SET_PAT_DATA', response.data)
        })
    },
}
```

}

В самом компоненте Test.vue есть метод computed: {}

```
computed: {
    patient_data() {
        return this.$store.getters.PATIENT_DATA
    }
},
```

обращаюсь к стору и получаю данные.

Не срабатывает actions и mutations, как данные лежали пустыми так и приходят в компонент пустые, что я делаю не так?

Comment: вы показали computed который возвращает  данные из store, по вашим словам данные получаются но "Не срабатывает actions и mutations", но вы не дали кода как вы вызываете actions/mutations.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько я не понимаю как вызвать actions\mutations в компоненте...что бы получить данные приходящие в api и положить их в какой нибудь обьект

Comment: мутации в кмопоненте многие не советую вызывать, вызывайте их в действиях, а действия можно импортировать через `mapActions` или вызвать напрямую, например, если в компоненте: `this.$store.dispatch('action', payload)`